# Maven site fails while building javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I try to build a site for my minecraft plugin but it fails during javadoc generation. I have my pom.xml and the log in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Trqhxrd/c4d80120c5ef920f4869161d4f73b115).

When I run `mvn clean site` it fails while generating javadoc because it does not find the dependencies used in my program. The problem is, that these dependencies are usually provided by the server, which tries to run the plugin so it does not make any sense to compile these dependencies. For some dependencies it is even forbidden to compile them. For example the spigot-api, which is part of the `io.papermc.paper:paper-api`-dependency.

And the weird thing is, it works just fine in IntelliJ. When I run the `mvn clean site`-command in IntelliJ using a run configuration it works just fine.

I already tried the `additionalDependencies` option but it did not improve the result.

I could stop it from failing the build by setting `failOnError` and `failOnWarning` to false but I still don't want these errors in my log.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Sincerely yours,

Trqhxrd

Comment: And what is the failure reason? Log output ?

Comment: The failure reason is, that he does not find packages and classes referenced in the import statements while generating javadoc. The log as well as the pom.xml are in the gist given.

Comment: Seems like a maven configuration issue. Can you verify that IntelliJ does not activate a maven profile (`mvn -Pxxx`)? Are there any profiles defined in your local maven installation `~/.m2/settings.xml`?